# Magento 2 How to cancel invoiced order forcefully

Tags: magento2

I need to forcefully cancel the order even though invoiced is done. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to do without customization Or with customization also it breaks business logic and some other issue may happen.

As per rule also, When Invoice generated means we recieved the money.

Respecting accounting standards, the correct way is to generate Credit memo to close the order.